# Screen Scraping in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, screen-scraping, nokogiri

What are the screen scraping options in Rails 3 - gem/library? I have used Nokogiri in the past but just wanted to know if there are better options in Rails 3.

Comment: IMO Nokogiri is the best scraping lib available for any language. Maybe you should tell us what it doesn't have that you want.

Comment: @pguardiario: Nokogiri is best, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one-off task or if your target data set is relatively small (under a hundred of pages), use [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) (browse & scrape) or [Anemone](https://github.com/chriskite/anemone) (does whatever Mechanize does + some additional crawling-specific options).

If you need to automate this collection or if you are dealing with large data sets, consider using a web service. [Bobik](http://usebobik.com) is a good choice in this bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't do screen scraping. You are free to use Ruby code that would add that functionality, but by itself it does the generation of the pages.

Mechanize, which uses Nokogiri internally, is a good choice, otherwise I always roll my own using Nokogiri and OpenURI.

Answer (score 0):

In the fantastic [RubyTools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) website you can find several [Ruby libraries to parsing HTML](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/html_parsing). Still Nokogiri is the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Scrapifier](https://github.com/tiagopog/scrapifier) gem to get metadata from URIs found in a string. It's very simple to use:

```
'Wow! What an awesome site: http://adtangerine.com!'.scrapify

 #=> {
 #   title:       "AdTangerine | Advertising Platform for Social Media",
 #   description: "AdTangerine is an advertising platform that uses the tangerine as a virtual currency for advertisers and publishers in order to share content on social networks.",
 #   images:      ["http://adtangerine.com/assets/logo_adt_og.png", "http://adtangerine.com/assets/logo_adt_og.png", "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/adtangerine-prod/users/avatars/000/000/834/thumb/275747_1118382211_1929809351_n.jpg", "http://adtangerine.com/assets/foobar.gif"],
 #   uri:         "http://adtangerine.com"
 # }
```